# Processing with leapmotion , cursor display

Tags: java, processing, leap-motion

I am working on leapmotion in processing. I am making a simple application that will trace the index_finger movement and sketch it... 
everything is fine...my project is tracing my pointer and sketching as required but the problem the problem is when I stop sketching (I used circular motion for enabling sketch and tap motion to stop) there is nothing that can tell me where my cursor is... I have to guess the position of my index_finger pointer.
here is what I have done so far...

```
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
    import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

    import com.leapmotion.leap.Controller;
    import com.leapmotion.leap.Finger;
    import com.leapmotion.leap.Frame;
    import com.leapmotion.leap.Pointable;
    import com.leapmotion.leap.Hand;
    import com.leapmotion.leap.Tool;
    import com.leapmotion.leap.Vector;
    import com.leapmotion.leap.Gesture;
    import com.leapmotion.leap.processing.LeapMotion;

    LeapMotion leapMotion;

    ConcurrentMap<Integer, Integer> fingerColors;
    ConcurrentMap<Integer, Integer> toolColors;
    ConcurrentMap<Integer, Vector> fingerPositions;
    ConcurrentMap<Integer, Vector> toolPositions;


    float hey = 21;
    float hi = 15;
    float hoo = 0;

    boolean circle_me = false;
    boolean tap_me = false;

    void setup()
    {
      size(16 * 50, 9 * 50);
      background(250);
      frameRate(60);
      ellipseMode(CENTER);

      leapMotion = new LeapMotion(this);
      fingerColors = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
      fingerPositions = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Vector>();
    }

    void draw()
    {
       text("Sketch Pad", 250,80);

      for (Map.Entry entry : fingerPositions.entrySet())
      {
        Integer fingerId = (Integer) entry.getKey();
     //   println ("finger_id: " + fingerId);
        Vector position = (Vector) entry.getValue();
    //    fill(fingerColors.get(fingerId));
        if (keyPressed && (key == 'd') || circle_me == true){    
        smooth();
        fill(random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),120);
    //    fill(255, 0, 0, 25);
        //stroke(0);
        noStroke();
        ellipseMode(CENTER);
        ellipse(leapMotion.leapToSketchX(position.getX()), leapMotion.leapToSketchY(position.getY()), 25.0, 25.0);

        }
        //else
        //pencil(position);

        if(tap_me){
          circle_me = false;
          tap_me = false;
        }


        /*
        else{
          //fill(100);
          //rect(0,0,width,height);
          ellipseMode(CENTER);
          ellipse(leapMotion.leapToSketchX(position.getX()), leapMotion.leapToSketchY(position.getY()), 5.0, 5.0);
        }
        */


        if (keyPressed && (key == 'e'))
           background(255);


      }

    }

    boolean pencil(Vector position){

        if(hoo == 0){
          hi = leapMotion.leapToSketchX(position.getX());
          hey = leapMotion.leapToSketchY(position.getY());
          hoo++;
        }
        line(leapMotion.leapToSketchX(position.getX()), leapMotion.leapToSketchY(position.getY()), hi, hey);
        hi = leapMotion.leapToSketchX(position.getX());
        hey = leapMotion.leapToSketchY(position.getY());
        strokeWeight(1);
       // println("x: " + position.getX() + "\n y: " + position.getY());
    return true;
    }

    void onInit(final Controller controller)
    {
      controller.enableGesture(Gesture.Type.TYPE_CIRCLE);
      controller.enableGesture(Gesture.Type.TYPE_KEY_TAP);
      // enable background policy
      controller.setPolicyFlags(Controller.PolicyFlag.POLICY_BACKGROUND_FRAMES);
    }

    void onFrame(final Controller controller)
    {
      Frame frame = controller.frame();
      for (Gesture gesture : frame.gestures())
      {
        if ("TYPE_CIRCLE".equals(gesture.type().toString()) && "STATE_START".equals(gesture.state().toString())) {
          //circle_me = true;
          println("circled " + gesture.duration());
        }
        else if ("TYPE_CIRCLE".equals(gesture.type().toString()) && "STATE_STOP".equals(gesture.state().toString())) {
          circle_me = true;
          println("circledS " + gesture.duration());
        }
        else if ("TYPE_KEY_TAP".equals(gesture.type().toString()) && "STATE_STOP".equals(gesture.state().toString())) {
              if ("TYPE_KEY_TAP".equals(gesture.type().toString()) && "STATE_STOP".equals(gesture.state().toString())) {
              tap_me = true;
              println("tapped " + gesture.duration());
            }
        }
      }
      fingerPositions.clear();
      for (Finger finger : frame.fingers())
      {
        int fingerId = finger.id();
        color c = color(random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255));

        fingerColors.putIfAbsent(fingerId, c);

        if("TYPE_INDEX".equals(finger.type().toString())){

          fingerPositions.put(fingerId, finger.stabilizedTipPosition());
          String finger1 = finger.type().toString();
         // println ("index: " + finger.stabilizedTipPosition());
        //println("x: " + finger.getX() + "\n y: " + finger.getY());
        }
         /*
        if("TYPE_THUMB".equals(finger.type().toString())){

          String finger2 = finger.type().toString();

        //  fingerPositions.put(fingerId, finger.stabilizedTipPosition());
         // println ("thumb: " + finger.stabilizedTipPosition());
        }
        */
      }
    }
```

I need something that acts like a cursor when sketching mode is inactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to paint to an "offscreen buffer" using the PGraphics object and then draw that and your cursor to the screen. See https://www.processing.org/reference/createGraphics_.html

Here's an example, which I adapted from something else I had done. Press a key to turn painting on and off:

```
import com.leapmotion.leap.*;

int width = 800;
int height = 600;
int maxBrushSize = 120;
color canvasColor = 0xffffff;
float alphaVal = 10;
PGraphics canvas;
Boolean isDrawing = true;

Controller leap = new Controller();

void setup()
{
   frameRate(120);
   size(width, height);
   canvas = createGraphics(width, height);
   background(canvasColor);
   stroke(0x00ffffff);
}


void draw(){
  Frame frame = leap.frame();
  Pointable pointer = frame.pointables().frontmost();
  if( pointer.isValid() )
  {
    background(canvasColor);

    color frontColor = color( 255, 0, 0, alphaVal );
    color backColor  = color( 0, 0, 255, alphaVal );

    InteractionBox iBox = frame.interactionBox();
    Vector tip = iBox.normalizePoint(pointer.tipPosition());
    float x = tip.getX() * width;
    float y = height - tip.getY() * height;
    float brushSize = maxBrushSize - maxBrushSize * tip.getZ();

    if(isDrawing){
      canvas.beginDraw();
      canvas.fill(frontColor);
      canvas.noStroke();
      canvas.ellipse( x, y, brushSize, brushSize);
      canvas.endDraw();
    }
    image(canvas, 0, 0); //Draw canvas to screen

    noFill();
    stroke(0, 0, 0);
    ellipse( x, y, brushSize, brushSize); // draw cursor
  }
}

void keyPressed()
{
   isDrawing = !isDrawing;
}
```